# Unable to convert scientific notation value to decmial

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I followed an example from [Delphi Basic](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=StrToFloat). I copied it and able to run it well in my Delphi 2007.

So I build my own program and used this method as mentioned above but run into error. The error stated "...raised exception class EConvertError with message "9.702827253E+003' is not a valid floating point value".

Scratching my head.....

```
var
readResult2:WideString;
strSN:String;
strSN2:String;
floatSN:Extended;
```

when `readResult2` is read as '+9.702827253E+003'#$A as indicated in the watch,

```
strSN := readResult2;  
Delete(strSN,1,1);   
floatSN := StrToFloat(strSN);  //This line created an error
freqSformat.Text := FloatToStr(floatSN);
```

Any idea why it happened? I am still stumped...

Comment: one more thing to consider is the dot, if your program maybe would be run in other countries (or get dates form other countries) there is the chance there would be comma or some other character instead of dot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the trailing `#$A` character. I can't see where your text is coming from, but you need to remove that stray character.

```
StrToFloat('+9.702827253E+003'); // succeeds
StrToFloat('+9.702827253E+003'#$A); // raise EConvertError
```

A call to `Trim` would remove it.

```
StrToFloat(Trim('+9.702827253E+003'#$A)); // succeeds
```

But you'd surely be better off removing it properly. In order to know how to do that, you'd need to know where it came from in the first place. We don't know that. You do.

Comment: This value  was captured from the instrument. That explained  why.

Comment: The other thing you need to watch for is locale. If you execute the code on a machine with locale that uses `,` as decimal separator, and the instrument serves up text with `.` as decimal separator then you'll get caught out again.

Comment: `System.Val()` always use the dot as the separator, though. So it might be considered instead of `StrToFloat()`.

Comment: @David: indeed, if the string doesn't contain a comma as decimal separator on my German setup, then it fails with an EConvertError. It does not accept a full stop. But, as LU RD says, Val only accepts a full stop.

Comment: In order to deal with locale, one needs a clear understanding of the possible formats of the input data

Comment: @LURD Passing a format settings object is how I would probably go

Comment: David, yes the format settings record overload, [function StrToFloat(const S: string; const AFormatSettings: TFormatSettings): Extended;](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToFloat) is what you normally use.